# How can I merge these queries into one?

Tags: php, sql

I would like to know if there is a way to merge all these queries into one.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(status) as closedtickets FROM tickets WHERE status = 'c'
        SELECT COUNT(status) as pendingtickets FROM tickets WHERE status = 'p'
        SELECT COUNT(status) as onholdtickets FROM tickets WHERE status = 'h'
        SELECT COUNT(status) as opentickets FROM tickets WHERE status = 'o'";
```

Thanks, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'c') as closedtickets,
       SUM(status = 'p'),
       SUM(status = 'h'),
       SUM(status = 'o')
FROM tickets;
```